# Comparing attribute of a Mono versus An attribute of an object thats not a Mono (for an if (exists) else situation)

Tags: java, flux

I'm learning java flux, and i came to this problem.

What i want is:
If the object alrdy exists with the right status, i want to update it further in the code. If the object doesnt exists or has the wrong status i will make a new object.

I tried this by comparing two objects which could contain the same status, but one is 1 mono and the other is not. I have succeeded in my unit test fixing this using block. But when building the integration test the block make the compiler skip the rest of my code in this class when it reaches the block. And when I dont use the block i never get my value the same as the Object in our library, because they are diffent objects. From what i understand i should use as little .block as possible, so i prefer not to use it in this class but a class higher in the application.

```
@Override
public Mono<Id> handle(GetOrCreateObjectCommand command) {
    var id = command.getId();

    Mono<Object> object = objectCommandPort.getIdAndStatus(id);
    ObjectStatus objectStatus = object.map(object::getStatus).block();

    if (monoStatus.equals(ObjectStatus.STARTED)) {
        return object.map(Object::getObjectId);
    } else {
        return objectCommandPort
                .createObject(id)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(
                        new testException(
                                ERROR.message(e.getMessage()))));
    }}
```

So at the IF the status of the different objects will be checked on status. If its the same then get the Id. If not then make a new object. Also when the object doesnt exists, we want to create a new one.